# myTiming in Shifrin's book is outdated?

Tags: compatibility, timing

Recently I was reading *Mathematica® programming: an advanced introduction*, and found a function called [`myTiming`](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node297.html). It differs from build-in `Timing` function, as the author noted, in the way that it can measure small intervals of time.

However, perhaps due to the change of Mathematica syntax in newer versions, `myTiming` gets stuck after generating a number of warnings in version 11. The warning messages, together with my code, are attached below.

I am just a beginner for Mathematica, can anyone please give some suggestions on improvement?

```
Clear[myTiming];
myTiming[x_] := 
  Module[
    {z = 0, y = 0, timelim = 0.1, p, q, 
     iterlist = (Power[10, #] & /@ Range[0, 10]),
     nm = If[ToExpression[StringTake[$Version, 1]] < 6, 2, 1]},
    Catch[
      If[(z = Nest[First, Timing[(y++; Do [x, {#}]);], nm]) > timelim, 
        Throw[{z, y}]] & /@ iterlist] /. {p_, q_} :> p/iterlist[[q]]];
Attributes[myTiming] = {HoldAll};

myTiming[Sin[Range[1000]];]
```

> First::normal: Nonatomic expression expected at position 1 in
> First[0.].
>
> First::normal: Nonatomic expression expected at position 1 in
> First[0.].
>
> First::normal: Nonatomic expression expected at position 1 in
> First[0.015625].
>
> General::stop: Further output of First::normal will be suppressed
> during this calculation.

[image: Errors generated in run-time when calling the function]

Comment: A tip for debugging code in general: try pieces of the code on their own and see if it works. A tip for debugging in *Mathematica* (and other languages with good error messages, too): the error message mentions that there is an error when the function `First` is called. You can look up `First` in the documentation: it picks out the first element of a list. So this is saying that somewhere in the code, `First[0.]` happens, which it doesn't know what to do with. So check the code that has `First` in it.

Comment: So the code snippet `Nest[First, Timing[(y++; Do[x, {#}]);], nm]` seems weird. I'm not sure exactly what that is supposed to be doing. Can you check to make sure that you've copied that correctly? That's where the error is.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This code was written sometime ago, and it seems to use `StringTake[$Version, 1]` to decide whether it is running in a version earlier than 6. That works well for single-digit version numbers, but would have broken as of version 10.

The reason for checking is that before version 6, `Timing` used to report the time not as a plain number but multiplied by `Second`. In other words, it would return something like `{0.1 Second, result}`.

Then `0.1` can be extracted by doing `First` twice, hence the `Nest` construction that applies `First` either once or twice, depending on the version.

If it's not necessary to run this in very old versions, just use `First[Timing[...]]` (or even better, `AbsoluteTiming`):

```
Clear[myTiming];
myTiming[x_] := 
  Module[{z = 0, y = 0, timelim = 0.1, p, q, iterlist = 10^Range[0, 10]}, 
    Catch[
      If[(z = First[AbsoluteTiming[(y++; Do[x, {#}]);]]) > timelim, 
         Throw[{z, y}]] & /@ iterlist] /. {p_, q_} :> p/iterlist[[q]]];
Attributes[myTiming] = {HoldAll};

myTiming[Sin[Range[1000]]]

(* 0.000219619 *)
```

Note that version 10.1 introduced a built-in function, [`RepeatedTiming`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RepeatedTiming.html) which may be useful. For example, it also offers the ability to time the operation for (at least) a specified number of seconds.

Answer (score 4):

As pointed out [by ilian](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/162272/1871), it's the `ToExpression[StringTake[$Version, 1]]` that's causing trouble. I'd like to complement that, the easiest way to update this function without breaking compatibility is to use `$VersionNumber`, which is introduced in version 2:

```
Clear[myTiming];
myTiming[x_] := 
  Module[{z = 0, y = 0, timelim = 0.1, p, q, 
    iterlist = (Power[10, #] & /@ Range[0, 10]), nm = If[$VersionNumber < 6, 2, 1]}, 
   Catch[If[(z = Nest[First, Timing[(y++; Do[x, {#}]);], nm]) > timelim, 
        Throw[{z, y}]] & /@ iterlist] /. {p_, q_} :> p/iterlist[[q]]];
Attributes[myTiming] = {HoldAll};

Sin@Range[1000] // myTiming
```

[image]

### Remark

The reason that Leonid doesn't use `$VersionNumber` in `myTiming` might be, he is trying to illustrate the core-language feature of *Mathematica* as much as possible with `myTiming`. (For example, the rule `{p_, q_} :> p/iterlist[[q]]` looks rather intentional. ) As stated in the book:

> The code is a bit involved to explain now, but after reading through the book it may be a good idea to revisit it, since it illustrates many points.

For readability, I would code `myTiming` as follows:

```
Clear[myTiming];
myTiming[x_] := 
  With[{timelim = 0.1, range = Range[0, 10], 
    take = If[$VersionNumber < 6, #[[1, 1]] &, #[[1]] &]}, 
   Catch[Scan[
     With[{times = 10^#}, 
       With[{timing = take@Timing@Do[x, {times}]}, 
        If[timing > timelim, Throw[timing/times]]]] &, range]]];
Attributes[myTiming] = {HoldAll};
```